# set attribute regarding to condition ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, razor

Is there anyway to do this?

```
<tr @if (i % 2 == 0) { class="odd" }>
```

Comment: I have no idea what the syntax is for Razor stuff, but would `@(i % 2 == 0 ? "class=\"odd\"" : "")` work?

Comment: Close :), it did render the following:
<tr class=""odd"">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<tr class=@(i % 2 == 1 ? "odd" : "even")>...</tr>
```

Comment: Done :).. for some reason I wasn't allowed to flag it as an answer until 4mins (and yeah I went away for a few hours :))